# Losing data when using Camera in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-camera, android-viewpager

I'm new to this whole android development scene, so sorry if i ask a stupid question but i can't find an answer to this.

I currently have a ViewPager with a button that starts the camera and updates an ImageView with a picture that it took. The problem is on the emulator (4.1.2) and on a Motorola Razor x910 (4.0.4) it works perfectly,it gets the picture from the camera and updates the ImageView with the picture. But on an Galaxy S3 (4.1) and a Motorola Milestone (2.3.7) it crashes and gives a null reference (the ImageView is set to null after using the camera) so it cannot assign the picture to the ImageView and crashes

Any advice?